# Send server socket newthread message in Python3

Tags: python, serversocket, tcpserver

I tried to run an example program of a socket server that receives and sends messages in Python3 as follows:

```py
 from threading import Thread
 from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
class ClientThread(Thread):
  m_request = ""
  m_answer = ""
  def __init__(self,data):
  Thread.__init__(self)

  self.m_request =data

  def run(self):
 global QUIT
 try:
  self.m_answer = textprotocol.processCommand(self.m_request)
except str:
  log.save("exception %s"%str)

  def answer(self):
   return self.m_answer
```

I am trying to send a message back to the client using this code:

```py
newthread = ClientThread(line)
  newthread.start()
  while newthread.isAlive():
   pass
  conn.send(newthread.answer())  # echo
  newthread.join()
  del newthread
  newthread = None
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
conn.send(newthread.answer())  # echo
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I don't know where to insert the `encode('utf-8')` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick

```
def answer(self):
   return self.m_answer.encode('utf8')
```

It might be easier to store self.m_answer as a bytes like object but converting it here should be fine.

Comment: this seems to work!

Comment: thanks! this seems to work